# Facebook Graph Api Is it possible to know, if a user use a specific application, or game

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph Api, is it possible, for a web site with FB Login implemented, to know if a user use, or have installed, a specific application, or game.

I want to create a community around certain game on facebook, and would use this to prevent non user of the app to register on my site.

Comment: Let say the game is ChessGame,   Witch is not one of my app.  Is it possible, in any manner to know if the visiting user of my site, have or not this game installed.

Comment: No, this is not possible.